# What do you call a smug response whose intention is primarily to make the responder look clever?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

At one time or another, you've probably inquired about something (perhaps online) and been met with the curt or critical response.  It's meant to showcase their cleverness.  It's more of a concealed boast than it is a help.  Is there a word or phrase which calls out is the disingenuousness of the help, since it's not that at all?

This word or phrase characterizes **the response and not the person or the behavior**.

Comment: Sounds like _softballing_.

Comment: That could be called "showing off" …

Comment: Anybody we know?

Comment: ' gopher is in sunbathing'

Comment: OP there states
'I'm looking for a single word to most aptly describe a person' and accepted 'grandstanding', the action not the person. _This question already has answers [t]here_, or answers ('grandstander') so close as to be redundant if echoed.

Comment: I have voted to re-open, but you (the OP) needs to clarify and provide better details. So far we feel like the goal posts have changed at least once, due to the many edits (like 7 now)

Comment: I could see I hadn't clearly explained, since I had asked to describe the response, not the person or the behavior.  It was marked as duplicate, which I felt was completely not the case, so I tried to clarify and draw attention to the response.  I tried to delete the question, but it wasn't allowed for all the effort put in.  I have always been obsessive compulsive about trying to clearly articulate.  Backfired here.  My fault.

Comment: I believe I was clear (e.g. even going back to my initial post, before edits) that this was always about *the response* and not the behavior or person.  I liked "grandstanding" but it missed that aspect.

Comment: The trouble is once I realized I had missed the mark, I had no good way of correcting things.  I tried to close the question.  Not allowed.  I tried to reframe, but that didn't help much either.  I had unintentionally been painted into a corner.  I apologize.  I didn't mean for it to go this way.

Answer (score 3):

This can be called **grandstanding,** [defined by Cambridge as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grandstanding)

> acting or speaking in a way intended to attract the good opinion of other people who are watching

Comment: That's pretty good.  I'd like to leave the question open for a while to hear other potential terms.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This might fit some cases:
[Macmillan Dictionary **showboating**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/showboating)
"behavior that is intended to make people notice and admire you"

Answer (score 2):

In the UK it's a ***planted question*** (***softball question*** in the US, ***Dorothy Dixer*** in Australia). That means asking a question for the sole purpose of allowing the responder (often, your party leader, if you're an MP) to reply in a way that reflects well on him and/or your political party.

It's kinda the opposite of a ***loaded question***, which is usually intended to make the responder look ***bad***. In neither case does the person asking have any interest in ***learning*** anything from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **playing to the crowd**.

Definition from the [Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+to+the+crowd) :

> To act, behave, or perform in such a way as to receive as much
> approval from an audience or group of spectators as one can get,
> especially the lowest common denominator therein.

Example from "Back to Birmingham: Richard Arrington, Jr., and His Times" by Jimmie Lewis Franklin:

> While he never fit the classic definition of political demagogue, the
> press and opponents did accuse him of shifting positions to suit his
> political advantage and of *playing to the crowd*, habits not uncommon
> to some other politicians.